# Why do I keep getting this error in Swift? 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent'

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm trying to get this rectangle to repeat but I keep getting this error message saying this. I tried everything but I cant seem to figure it out. Can someone please help Its so frustrating I cant get pass this part. I ve been stuck on this error for a couple of days now. If you need more info please message me.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:  >name:'(null)' texture:[ 'longrec'

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    let longRec = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "longrec")


   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
       repeatlongRec()
   }

   func longRec() {
    let moveToTheLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-self.size.width, y: 0, duration: 2.0)
    let repeatMoveToLeft = SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveToTheLeft)
    let removeFromScene = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([repeatMoveToLeft, removeFromScene])


    longRec.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 0.5, self.size.height / 2)
    longRec.zPosition = 15
    longRec.runAction(sequence)
    addChild(longRec)        
    }

   func repeatlongRec() {
   let generateLongRec = SKAction.sequence([
   SKAction.runBlock(self.longRec),
   SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0)])
   let endlessAction = SKAction.repeatAction(generateLongRec, count: 4)
   runAction(endlessAction)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    let longRec = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rectangle.png")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        let makeLongRec = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(generateLongRec), SKAction.waitForDuration(3)])
        runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(makeLongRec, count: 4))
    }

    func generateLongRec() {

        longRec.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2)
        longRec.zPosition = 15
        self.addChild(longRec)
        let moveToTheLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-self.size.width, y: 0, duration: 2.0)
        let removeFromScene = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        longRec.runAction(SKAction.sequence([moveToTheLeft, removeFromScene]))
    }
```

The issue with your code is that, you are adding it too fast. Like @Ace Green said, you are adding the node before you even remove it.

Two other things you should be aware of:

1. try not to use the same name for both `func` and your node.
2. if you are planning to use only one node and repeat adding it. The wait time in `waitforDuration(2)` in `didMoveToView` should always be larger than the duration in `let moveToTheLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-self.size.width, y: 0, duration: 2.0)`, otherwise you will still have the same `Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent` issue. One way to resolve this is to declare an array of node.

Comment: I tried the code in the didMoveToView and Im getting errors.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Try to change the waitforDuration() to 3. As I said, this should always be larger.

Comment: I did that I still get an error in the didMoveToView it says extra argument in call by this part of the code: sequence(SKAction

Comment: I see why now, I made a mistake in the line of code in didMoveToView. I just updated it, try it, it should work now.

Comment: I get an error saying Missing argument for parameter count in call

Comment: Before I update the code again, do you want to repeat the action 4 times? or repeat forever?

Comment: I need it to repeat 4 times. Sorry if I don't respond back its getting late and I have to get some sleep thank you for your help. I will look over the code tommorow and tell you if it works.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I just tested and updated the code under didMoveToView. It was a good learning for me too. I found that, if you are using `SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction, count)`, you cannot use sequence. But if you are using `SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction)`, it is alright. That's why you got the error.

Comment: I got rid of the repatMoveToLeft in the generateLongRec() and it works like you said but the rectangle moves really fast and disappears. It doesn't fully move to the left because Im not repeating the moveToTheLeft action. Also I need it to come later on in my scene.... I tried using waitForDuration but I get that same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77469/discussion-between-f-qi-and-newtocoding).

Answer (score 1):

After you do addChild(longRec) you never remove it

So when you execute func repeatlongRec() it crashes because the node is still there.

try to restructure both functions so that you remove the node whenever you don't are done with it then repeat the process

Comment: Could you please give me the code because Im not understanding it. I thought I did that in the other func longRec where I put removeFromParent in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I would try doing it this way:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

   let longRec = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "longrec")

   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

       var timer = NSTimer .scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: Selector("longRec") , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

   }

   func longRec() {
    let moveToTheLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-self.size.width, y: 0, duration: 2.0)
    let removeFromScene = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveToTheLeft, removeFromScene])
    let repeatSequence = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence)

    longRec.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 0.5, self.size.height / 2)
    longRec.zPosition = 15

    longRec.runAction(repeatSequence)   

    addChild(longRec) 

    }
}
```